# Unable to get the simplified coordinates using sympy - python

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have x2, x3, y2, y3, d1, d2, d3 values which is,

```
x2 = 0
x3 = 100
y2 = 0
y3 = 0
d1 = 100
d2 = 100
d3 = 87
```

When I use the below script,

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols('x y')
eq1 = Eq((x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 - d2 ** 2)
eq2 = Eq((x - x3) ** 2 + (y - y3) ** 2 - d3 ** 2)

sol_dict = solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
```

I got the ans as,

```
sol_dict = [(12431/200, -87*sqrt(32431)/200), (12431/200, 87*sqrt(32431)/200)]
```

How can I achieve the simplified solution like

```
sol_dict = [(62.155, -78.33), (62.155, 78.33)]
```

in python?

Comment: Try calling `.evalf()` on each individual number you got from SymPy.

Comment: @ForceBru, Thank you for your suggestion. It works for me, when I change Eq((x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 - d2 ** 2) as Eq((x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 - d2 ** 2).evalf()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can numerically evaluate the solution to get floats:

```py
In [40]: [[x.evalf(3) for x in s] for s in sol_dict]                                                                              
Out[40]: [[62.2, -78.3], [62.2, 78.3]]
```

I would only recommend doing that for display though. If you want to use the values in sol_dict for further calculations it's best to keep them as exact rational numbers.